# Plasticscm service not started in windows 8.1

Tags: plasticscm

I commit to be a beginner using this tool. Well, I installed it and I can configure server and client, even with mySQL as Database. However, I'm not able to connect to the server. When I chek the services which should run, the plasticscm server stopped. If I try to start it, it stops again telling that some services are stopped if they are not used by other programs or services. My question is now, how to change this setting or bypass it in plasticscm?

Forgot to mention it's version 5.0.4.603. Tried it as well with 5.4.15.605

Here are the errors in the log file:

2014-09-22 20:38:32,738 (null) ACER\Ueli at (null) INFO  Transaction - Transaction timeout -> 120000ms
2014-09-22 20:38:33,113  ACER\Ueli at  INFO  Channel - 'sinklevel' compression mode set. all metadata will be serialized
2014-09-22 20:38:33,113  ACER\Ueli at  INFO  Channel - 'BufferPoolMax' is set to '10'. It sets the maximum number of available buffers for object data transfers
2014-09-22 20:38:33,113  ACER\Ueli at  INFO  Channel - 'SerializationObjectsAtSink' is set to 'True'. True means SerializationBase descendants are  directly written into the response buffer
2014-09-22 20:38:33,129  ACER\Ueli at  INFO  Channel - Start listening
2014-09-22 20:38:33,129  ACER\Ueli at  INFO  Channel - 'sinklevel' compression mode set. all metadata will be serialized
2014-09-22 20:38:33,129  ACER\Ueli at  INFO  Channel - 'BufferPoolMax' is set to '10'. It sets the maximum number of available buffers for object data transfers
2014-09-22 20:38:33,129  ACER\Ueli at  INFO  Channel - 'SerializationObjectsAtSink' is set to 'True'. True means SerializationBase descendants are  directly written into the response buffer
2014-09-22 20:38:33,129  ACER\Ueli at  INFO  Channel - Creating self-signed certificate 'ssl-certificate.pfx' for host 'acer'
2014-09-22 20:38:33,144  ACER\Ueli at  FATAL Daemon - Remoting configuration failed with the exception 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Mono.Security.X509.Extensions.SubjectAltNameExtension..ctor(System.String[], System.String[], System.String[], System.String[])'.
   at Codice.Channels.SelfSignedCertificate.GeneratePkcs12Certificate(String fileName, String hostName, DateTime validFrom, DateTime validTill, String plainTextPassword, String[] alternativeHostNames, String[] alternativeIpAddresses)
   at Codice.Channels.SelfSignedCertificate.GenerateHostCertificateIfNeeded()
   at Codice.Channels.SslServerChannel.ProcessPfxCertificate(String certFileName)
   at Codice.Channels.SslServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider serverSinkProvider)
   at Codice.Channels.PlasticSecuredTcpChannel.Init(IDictionary properties, IClientChannelSinkProvider clientSink, IServerChannelSinkProvider serverSink)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.CreateChannelFromConfigEntry(ChannelEntry entry)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.ConfigureChannels(RemotingXmlConfigFileData configData, Boolean ensureSecurity)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.ConfigureRemoting(RemotingXmlConfigFileData configData, Boolean ensureSecurity)'.

ACER is my machine and Ueli the user. This was with 5.4.15.605

remoting.conf:

```
<configuration>
    <system.runtime.remoting>
        <application>
            <channels>
                <channel type="Codice.Channels.PlasticTcpChannel,plastictcpchannel" port="8087" name="normal">
                    <serverProviders>
                        <formatter type="Codice.Channels.PlasticBinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider, plastictcpchannel" typeFilterLevel="Full" Compression="sinklevel" SerializationObjectsAtSink="true" BufferPoolMax="10"/>
                        <provider type="Codice.CM.Server.ExceptionTracerSinkProvider, servercommon" />
                    </serverProviders>
                    <clientProviders>
                        <provider type="Codice.Channels.ClientSinkProvider, plastictcpchannel" />
                        <formatter ref="binary" />
                    </clientProviders>
                </channel>

                <channel type="Codice.Channels.PlasticSecuredTcpChannel, plastictcpchannel" port="8088" sslPfxFile="ssl-certificate.pfx" sslPfxFilePassword="|SoC|2ogBDa8GmifTjC7UKp4KuoF0/jWYlXy2" name="secured">
                    <serverProviders>
                        <formatter type="Codice.Channels.PlasticBinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider, plastictcpchannel" typeFilterLevel="Full" Compression="sinklevel" SerializationObjectsAtSink="true" BufferPoolMax="10"/>
                        <provider type="Codice.CM.Server.ExceptionTracerSinkProvider, servercommon" />
                    </serverProviders>
                    <clientProviders>
                        <provider type="Codice.Channels.ClientSinkProvider, plastictcpchannel" />
                        <formatter ref="binary" />
                    </clientProviders>
                </channel>
            </channels>
        </application>
    </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi orca. Well, let's try the following: check the file plastic.server.log which is in the same path as your plasticd.exe (server binary). It should contain an explanation of why the server is not starting up. Let me know what it says and we'll go from there. Alternatively there's a known procedure you can follow: you can go to the command line, go to the plastic server's directory and type plasticd --console and it will start in console mode, which is normally faster than going to the services window and starting stopping. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi,I reinstalled it now but it still doesn't work. As per your request, I started it by console and it's still not running. There's a FATAL Daemon in the log telling remote configuration failed. And several other erros (too big for a comment here). I try to add it to my previous post.

Comment: Hi, Checking the log (System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Mono.Security.X509.E), it seems a missing library issue. Could you check if there is a "Mono.Secourity" and a "Mono.Posix" library in your server folder? In addition, what´s is your installe .NET framework version?

Comment: Could you also post your "remoting.conf" file? I would like to review if it´s corrupt for some reason

Comment: I use .Net 4.5.1. And yes, mono.posix.dll and mono.sciruty.dll are in the server folder. I add the remoting.conf above in the previous post.

Comment: Could you reach me at:   calba at codicesoftware dot com    ??                   I would like to get connected to check the issue and faster debug what´s happening. Then, I will update the post with the extended informaton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the issue, it was related to the configured SSL channel in the "remoting.conf" file.  After disabling it (@orca actually didn´t want to use it), the issue is not happening again.

If you review the "remoting.conf" file, it has two channels, a TCP channel and a SSL optional channel.